# text not displaying in CheckedListBox in Visual Basic

Tags: vba, vb6, checkedlistbox

Following code doesn't display text in CheckedListBox but shows in ListBox

```
DisplayChapter = match.Value.Replace("</a>", "").Replace(">", "")
ListBox1.Items.Add(DisplayChapter)
CheckedListBox1.Items.Add(DisplayChapter)
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution by

Removing new line in the string . checkedListBox is not able to display text in a single line by removing new line character